# Relative references for named range and column in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy only a few fields in a named range, that have a cell value that aren't blank in the 'quantity' field.
I have 12 named ranges and at the top left of the range, I have a heading for every range. I simply need to copy the fields to another workbook.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim headingCheck As boolean,  i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, d As Boolean, Wb As Workbook  
'i is to keep track of rows, j is temporary variable for columns,headingCheck to keep track if heading has been placed or not
i = 15 ' starts pasting on the 15th line on the other workbook

For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("named_range") 'I have only defined the quantity column as a range since i didn't know how to search through the 2nd column in the range
headingCheck = false 'at the start, the heading hasn't been copied
If cell.Value > 0 Then
    If headingCheck = False Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F15").Copy Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) ' copies the heading if it hasn't been copied
        headingCheck = True ' will not copy heading again
        i = i + 1 ' next line
    End If
    
    j = -2 'starts from 2 columns before the quantity column as it contains the name of product
    For j = -2 To 2
        cell.Offset(0, j).Copy Wb.Sheets(1).Cells(i, j + 8)
    Next j
    i = i + 1
End If
Next
headingCheck = False
i = i + 1
```

I am copy-pasting this code for every named range, which I know is very inefficient. Does someone have a better idea? I want to iterate through all named ranges and to copy the heading, I have to define the absolute reference of the cell every time. If someone can tell me how to use the top left of the named range as the heading title all of it could be easier.

I also only want excel to go through only one column from the named range to search if quantity is more than 0. How can I do that?

```
For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("named_range").Columns(2)
```

Using columns(2) doesn't seem to work either, as it gives VBA type mismatch error. I don't know why.

Sample data:

| Item | Price | Quantity | Fabric | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Furniture** |  |  |  |  |
| Chair | 12 | 2 | Charcoal | 24 |
| Sofa | 25 | 1 | Ash | 25 |

Comment: `range("blah").cells(1)` ? For the columns you need `Columns(2).cells` I think. Perhaps you could loop through the `Names` collection.

Comment: Change the code to a Function and pass in the Range Names. This way you can select which Range Names you process since I'm sure you don't want to process all of your named ranges?

Comment: @SJR Thanks and Is there a way to copy over two cells with this method? like A1 and A2?

Comment: @RetiredGeek Thanks a lot, I've never used functions in VBA but it seems like a great idea now, what would the return type be for this function?

Comment: You could use `Resize`. If the top left cell of your range is A1 then `range("blah").cells(1).resize(2)` will comprise A1 and A2.

Comment: From what I can see you'd want to return headingCheck so your return type would be Boolean. Actually, I'd name the Function HeadingCheck and declare the function to return a boolean. You're already assigning headingCheck so you wouldn't need to change the code only the Function & End Function lines added with appropriate declarations for item(s) passed in and out.

Comment: @RetiredGeek Perfect! The only issue I'm coming across now is how can I loop through my named ranges? When I pass the name of that range (that I have defined manually in excel) into that sub as an argument, it doesn't recognize it. How can I fix that?

Comment: Saram, pass the Range Name in as a String variable then just substitute the parameter for "named_range" in your code.